# Can't save my Preferences after app killed

Tags: android, xml, save, preferences

Hi I'm trying to implement a settings page on my Android App.
I defined a xml Preference file, where I implemented CheckBoxPreference and EditTextPreference.

All the settings work perfectly while running the app, but when I kill it I lose all the settings.

**Preference.xml file:**

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Connection">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:title="Auto Log-In"
        android:summary="Auto connect "
        android:key="autoLogIn" 
        android:enabled="true" 
        android:selectable="true"/>

    <EditTextPreference
        android:name="Server"
        android:summary="Change the default server"
        android:defaultValue="www.google.com"
        android:title="Change server to:"
        android:key="www.google.com" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

**Preferences.class**

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);\
    }
}
```

How do I make the app save the settings?

UPDATE:
I did some test, and on the Virtual device and on my old HTC Legend with android 2.1 the settings work fine! But they don't work on the *Samsung Galaxy S* with android 2.2! Does this make sense to anybody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem with a *soft reset** of my Samsung Galaxy S... can't belive I waisted an all day on a correct code.

Hope this will save some time to others.
Marco

**Soft reset*: Settings -> Privacy -> Factory data Reset.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any reason for the prefs not to be saved.
The prefs are saved immediately when you perform a change (e.g. checking the checkbox).

Are you sure you didn't simply confuse the key with the value? Your server key is `android:key="www.google.com"` Maybe that's why you think it is not saved?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set `android:persistent="true"` for the preferences you want to store in SharedPreferences. As given [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android%3apersistent).