# I want to open an activity after my main activity has loaded

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a project where my manifest is opening .MainActivity by default

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

I want to be able to open an info screen on top of that app where it tells about my app. from there the user can press back to get back to the Main Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start your `info screen Activity` in your `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` method with `startActivity()` method

Comment: That works perfect! i thought i had tried that and it didnt work but i was wrong. i have it my info activity starting with no title bar to tell users about my apps or changes when they happen. Thanks!

Comment: Well, there was one more thing i wanted this to do.

Can i have this only pop up when the app starts for the first time?

Comment: found answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562786/android-first-run-popup-dialog

Answer (score 0):

Use an `Intent` in your `MainActivity` with a `Button` click or however you want the input to work

`Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivityName.class);
 intent.putExtras("key", value);    // if you want to send data
 // other intent attributes such as flags
 startActivity(intent);`

[Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

If you are stuck on how to change `Activities` then you really should [Start Here](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) and go through the docs carefully so you understand the basics of the Android framework