# App Introduction to user on first installation

Tags: android, android-layout

I wonder how google does it?? When you first power your device on, A introduction to apps and features will be shown in green color when user touches it the element will disappear ! I tried searching google but i don't get exact idea of what that layout / element was? Please regret me if this was a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is definitely what you are looking for

[Holo-themed transparent demo overlays](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2419939)

Answer (score 2):

Are you just trying to do something on the first launch and then never again? Or are you looking for that look and feel? If so, it's probably just images and such layed out. If you want to test the first launch, there's a few ways to do it. One of the easiest is to create an empty file in the shared preferences in your onCreate() method, then check to see if it is there. If it's not there, you do your on first launch action and then create the file afterwards.

Check this out: [Determine if android app is the first time used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636141/determine-if-android-app-is-the-first-time-used)