# how to create tips or a guide for Android app

Tags: java, android

I really don't know how to ask. I want to know how to create tips or guides for and android app as ES File Explorer.

When you open this app the first time you can see a guide, that's I want to make but I don't know how to call it and how to create it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [ShowcaseView](http://amlcurran.github.io/ShowcaseView/) to display the tips. 
And SharedPreferences for checking if the apps is being started for the first time, as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13237848/1031556)