# Set visibility of TextView from different Layout not working Android

Tags: android, listview

Im using spinner to hide textview from different layout/xml but my code is not working and Im stuck on this :(

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                    (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);
    final LinearLayout asdasd = (LinearLayout) addView.findViewById(R.id.ll2);

                        first2 = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.txtfirst2);

                        first = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.txtfirst);

    final Spinner mySpinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

            mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                    String imc_met= mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    if (imc_met.toString().equals("1")){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        first.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        first2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        asdasd.invalidate();
                    }
 }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
```

feed_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd"
                android:id="@+id/ll2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd" >

                    <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtfirst2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="1st"
                    android:textColor="#212121"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />


                    <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtsecond2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="2nd"
                    android:textColor="#212121"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />


                    <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtthird2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="3rd"
                    android:textColor="#212121"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtfourth2"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="4th"
                        android:textColor="#212121"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtxquarley"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Final"
                        android:textColor="#212121"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd" >


                    <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtfirst"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="#212121"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtsecond"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="#212121"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtthird"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="#212121"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtfourth"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="#212121"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtquarterley"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="#212121"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
```

There's no error in logcat but I think this is the problem and I don't get it.

> W/ViewRootImpl﹕ Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent {
>   action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100,
>   metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8,
>   repeatCount=151480, eventTime=14043549, downTime=5803662, deviceId=1,
>   source=0x301 }

Already tried I've search but it still not working :( Been spending 5 hours on this. And still I can't hide the textview using the code above what should I do from this?

**Any help is much appreciated!**

**UPDATE**

Forgot to tell that feed_item.xml is used in **ListView** and its **Custom Adapter**.

**CustomAdapter**

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final int gradeid;
        final int subjectid;
        final int studentid;
        final String first;
        final String second;
        final String third;
        final String fourth;
        final String subjname;
        final String remrks;

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        final FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);

        TextView FirstG = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtfirst);
        TextView SecondG = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtsecond);
        TextView ThirdG = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtthird);
        TextView FourthG = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtfourth);
        TextView subname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subjectname);
        TextView quarterley = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtquarterley);
        TextView remarks = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtremarks);



        gradeid = item.getSgradeid();
        subjectid = item.getSubjectid();
        studentid = item.getStudentid();
        first = item.getFirst();
        second = item.getSecond();
        third = item.getThird();
        fourth = item.getFourth();
        subjname = item.getStudent_name();

        int subj_sum = 0;
        int finalgrade = 0;
        int rmrks1 = 0;
        int rmrks2 = 0;

        subj_sum = Integer.parseInt(first.toString()) + Integer.parseInt(second.toString()) +
                Integer.parseInt(third.toString()) + Integer.parseInt(fourth.toString());
        finalgrade = subj_sum / 4;

        if (first.toString().equals("0") || second.toString().equals("0") ||
                third.toString().equals("0") || fourth.toString().equals("0")) {
            quarterley.setText("0");

        }
        else {
            quarterley.setText(Integer.toString(finalgrade));
            rmrks1 = Integer.parseInt(quarterley.getText().toString());
            rmrks2 = rmrks1;
            if (rmrks2 > 75 || rmrks2 < 100) {
                remarks.setText("Passed");
            }
            else if (rmrks2 < 74) {
                remarks.setText("Failed");
            }
        }



        FirstG.setText(first);
        SecondG.setText(second);
        ThirdG.setText(third);
        FourthG.setText(fourth);
        subname.setText(subjname);

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        return convertView;
```

Comment: do you see the Toast message?

Comment: @Pooya yes the toast is working

Comment: Clean and rebuild?! Your code should kill the text view for sure, and you probably don't need the invalidate(). Is the declaration of the text views final as well? And definitely not assigned something somewhere else in the code?

Comment: @DanielWilson already tried but it still the same. See my update^

Comment: Ah that makes a fairly enormous difference :) We will probably need to see more code but generally you augment views in a list in a very different manner - by using the getView() function of the adapter itself. Lists are optimized to recycle views so you need to instruct them how to behave differently to normal views.

Comment: but the spinner is on different activity. if I can use the OnItemSelectedListener on my CustomAdapter it should work but I don't know how. I'll update my Question with my **Custom Adapter**.

Answer (score 1):

You could use shared preferences.

Set the Shared Preference(s) in the spinner's OnItemSelect listener; and retrieve them in the respective activity.

The following code, from [How to set a default value to SharedPreferences programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765376/how-to-set-a-default-value-to-sharedpreferences-programmatically), is an example for setting the SharedPreference(s) :-

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
        PREFS_NAME, 0);
if (prefs.getInt("key_weight", null) == null) {
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("key_weight", 75);
    editor.commit();
}
```

The following code is an example of retrieving from the SharedPreferences :-

```
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final boolean devmode = sp.getBoolean(getResources().getString(R.string.sharedpreferencekey_developermode),false);
```

Noting that R.string.sharedpreferencekey_developermode holds the Shared Preferences Key Name