# Spinner OnItemSelectedListener not working on CustomListAdapter

Tags: android, listview, spinner

I have spinner in different activity to select what quarter to show. To try if its working I only make toast for testing but its not showing.

I'm applying it my CustomListAdapter.

**FeedListAdapter Code**

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final int gradeid;
        final int subjectid;
        final int studentid;
        final String first;
        final String second;
        final String third;
        final String fourth;
        final String subjname;
        final String remrks;

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        final FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);

        first2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtfirst2);
        first3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtfirst);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                (LayoutInflater) activity.getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_grades, null);

        final Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) addView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                String imc_met= mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if (imc_met.equals("1")){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //first3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //first2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }


            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

return convertView;
    }
```

As I mention above the **Toast** its not showing. Whats the problem with my coding?

**Any help or suggestion is appreacited! I REALLY NEED YOUR HELP GUYS!!**

**UPDATE**

Here is my other post regarding to hide **textview** using **Spinner**. Btw I'm hiding a item which is in **CustomListAdapter**.

[Set visibility of TextView from different Layout not working Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656937/set-visibility-of-textview-from-different-layout-not-working-android][1])

Comment: You can test app in debug mode and make a breakpoint in line `String imc_met= mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();` and then see what value is returned. I think your String return "" instead of "1".

Comment: @SadeqShajary wait I'll try

Comment: You could also put imc_met into a toast before/without the if.

Comment: I also believe that you wouldn't normally put `onItemSelected` in `getView` as `getView` gets invoked for every item in the list. So you'd be setting the listener a number of times (not sure what effect that would have). Personally I put the listener in the activity rather than in the adapter.

Comment: Both tried but not showing.

Comment: Is the spinner displaying? It would appear that it is not, or that it shows nothing.

Comment: @MikeT I already tried that and the Toast is working but the textview that I want to hide is not hiding. Yes the spinner is displaying,

Comment: I'd suggest adding the following to your question :- 1) The activity in which the spinner is invoked (i.e the activity that uses setContentView to load the layout inwhich the spinner is defined). 2) The layout xml in which the spinner is defnied. 3) The layout xml that is inflated by the spinner adapter. 4) A logcat from a failed/not working run. It may be that the issues is outside of the afapter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109293/discussion-between-miket-and-meyka-jograt).

Answer (score 1):

After ascertaining that the real issue was making setting the visibility of the two TextViews defined in other layout. The suggestion was to use shared preferences. Setting the Shared Preference(s) in the spinner's OnItemSelect listener and retrieving them in the respective activity.

The following code, from [How to set a default value to SharedPreferences programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765376/how-to-set-a-default-value-to-sharedpreferences-programmatically), was provided for setting the SharedPreference(s) :-

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
            PREFS_NAME, 0);
    if (prefs.getInt("key_weight", null) == null) {
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("key_weight", 75);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

The following code was provided in regards to retrieving the SharedPreferences :-

```
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final boolean devmode = sp.getBoolean(getResources().getString(R.string.sharedpreferencekey_developermode),false);
```

*Noting that R.string.sharedpreferencekey_developermode holds the Shared Preferences Key Name*