# Run certain operations only when the app is first installed

Tags: android, runtime, startup

Let us presume that we have a function defined this way:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void RunFirstTime() {
        //...
    }
}
```

The very first time I install the app, I want to run `RunFirstTime()` but then any other time I run the app, that function should not run.

Is there a built-in way to do this?

Comment: See this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35062744/1860982

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use SharedPreferences and store a boolean variable when you are done with first run.

To be more clear, the code should be something like this:

```
public static void RunFirstTime() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean firstRun = sPref.getBoolean("firstRun", true);
    if(firstRun){
        //Do something here
        ....
        //Save firstRun = false in order to not repeat next time 
        Editor prefEdit = sPref.edit();
        prefEdit.putBoolean("firstRun", false);
        prefEdit.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why on earth didn't I think of this -- of course! Thanks. Can accept in 12

Answer (score 0):

Try code like this:

```
public boolean isFirstRun() {
    SharedPreferences sPref;
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean isFirstRun = sPref.getBoolean("FirstRun", true);
    Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    ed.putBoolean("FirstRun", false);
    ed.commit();
    return isFirstRun;
  }
```