# android - start an activity onTouch

Tags: java, android

In my app I have a countdown which counts from five to one. At the moment, the counter starts as soon as the activity is started. What I want is to stay at 5 seconds and wait to count down until the screen is touched. So the countdown timer should be started which a touch event.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {
    private static final String FORMAT = "%02d:%02d";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        new CountDownTimer(5000, 10) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                text.setText("" + String.format("%02d:%03d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished))
                ));

                if (animationRunning) {
                    cancel();
                }
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                text.setText("done!");
            }
        }.start();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your count down timer inside onTouch like below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {
    private static final String FORMAT = "%02d:%02d";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
        new CountDownTimer(5000, 10) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                text.setText("" + String.format("%02d:%03d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished))
                ));

                if (animationRunning) {
                    cancel();
                }
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                text.setText("done!");
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. and what would I do if the countdown is part of a method?

Comment: call your method inside onTouchEvent  or create a new countdown timer  for onTouchEvent  :)

Comment: So is there no way, to 'pause' the activity until the screen is touched for the first time the app is started?

Comment: place all your code inside a method and call that method inside onTouchEvent

Comment: if you only want it for first time then you have to save your first launch inside shared prefs, please accept the answer if helped :)

Comment: Can you specify how to do that? I'll do - the post is too young to accept an answer :)

Comment: refer   http://stackoverflow.com/a/7217834/6478047     ,you can also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636141/determine-if-android-app-is-the-first-time-used

Comment: Are shared preferences only for starting the first time at all, or every time the app is re-opened?

Comment: Only for first time, there is no need to save any thing for app reopened

Comment: No, but I'm creating an app and because it's on time the user shouldn't be need to start immediately after the activity is started, but when he taps to 'confirm' to start

Comment: write all code in a method and call that method inside onclickListner of confirm , no need to use shared preferences

Comment: Thanks, you brought me to an idea!

Answer (score 0):

Move this section of code to your onTouchEvent, because it's on activity create that is why its starting when your activity starts

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 10) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        text.setText("" + String.format("%02d:%03d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished))
        ));

        if (animationRunning) {
            cancel();
        }
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        text.setText("done!");
    }
}.start();
```

you should be fine