# Android how to check the app is installed for first time or not first time

Tags: android

I am android developer, i came into a scenario that i need to know is the app is already uninstalled in that device or not.

How can i achieve this scenario.

Step 1 :App is installed for first time
Step 2: Uninstalled the App
step 3: Again when the app is installed ,i need to do some thing with the app( if uninstalled previously).

Comment: You should save the device id in your server

Comment: Save something into a SharedPreference that you can then reference when the app launches... If the Preference has not been set then you are running for the first time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636141/determine-if-android-app-is-the-first-time-used/41822558#41822558

Comment: @GavinHarris read the question carefully

Comment: Check the below link. It is already answered [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217578/check-if-application-is-on-its-first-run)

Comment: @KarunShresthafair point. Question is vague though. "Already uninstalled", I am guessing that this would require the app to have been installed first right? In that case, you would have to (as you suggested) persist to another source (i.e., Server)...

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya please read the question again

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya can you please recheck the question once ..

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya can you please recheck the question once ..I asked that step 1  I installed the app                                                                                  step 2 i uninstalled the app                                                                                  step 3 when i again installed the app , i need to know whether the app is installed previously in my device or not

Comment: it is not allowing me to create new question ? Can you remove this as duplicate as i had updated the question?