# Choosing language at startup

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

i want add startup Activity for users to choose app language, how to make this activity to show only at startup and when the user chose the language the activity has to be gone forever?

Comment: Use `SharedPreference`.

Comment: Just launch this `Activity` and when the user chooses a required language use `Intent` to launch a new `Activity` and `finish()` to close it.

Comment: you need to store Language code or name  some where like SharedPrefrence or SQLite so each time when your app open you  first check about language status to be set or not .

Comment: see link it could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636141/determine-if-android-app-is-the-first-time-used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you wish to display that activity only when the user runs the app for the first time.

Well, here's what you can do:

1) Get a handle to a [SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). This is to store if the user has already selected the language or not.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

2) Create a SharedPreferences.Editor

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
```

3) Store the information in a key-value

```
editor.putBoolean("HAS_SELECTED_LANGUAGE", true);
```

4) Commit the change

```
editor.commit();
```

5) Check if 'HAS_SELECTED_LANGUAGE' is true in the onCreate() of the activity, if so move on to the next Activity/Fragment/etc

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    ...
    if (sharedPref.getBoolean("HAS_SELECTED_LANGUAGE", false)) {
        //Replace with your action to perform if it is already selected
    }
    ...
}
```

Also it would be recomended to allow the user to be able to come back and change the language from somewhere else if and when they require.

Hope this solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify resources tailored to the culture of the people who use your app. You can provide any resource type that is appropriate for the language and culture of your users. For example, the following screenshot shows an app displaying string and drawable resources in the device's default (en_US) locale and the Spanish (es_ES) locale.

```
    <resources>
        <string name="hello_world">Hello World!</string>
    </resources>
```

[image]

```
    <resources>
        <string name="hello_world">¡Hola Mundo!</string>
    </resources>
```

Read developer documentation as per your logic below.

[Supporting Different Languages and Cultures](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)