# How to check if activity just loaded or restored

Tags: android

I want to check whether an activity just launched or not - so that I can perform (first time startup only actions e.g. attempt to load something and if it fails the first time let the user manually do it)

Currently I am doing this by checking if `savedInstanceState == null` on an `Activity.onCreate` method.

I am wondering how reliable this is? Is there a better alternative? Will `savedInstanceState == null` in any other scenario other than on Activity startup?

Comment: Read https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: Kindly check https://stackoverflow.com/a/41822558/3395198

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `SharedPreferences` at `onCreate()` method of otheractivity

```
 SharedPreferences wmbPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean isFirstRun = wmbPreference.getBoolean("FIRSTRUN", true);
    if (isFirstRun) {
    //do something
    }
```

By using this even if user delete app data by mistake this code will re-run.

You must be ready if the data is removed by user this could be achieved by `SharedPreferences`