# (Android) Get user to input information only once

Tags: android, android-studio

I want user to input some information on the first time they start the app so that those information can be used from that on. What are the possible ways to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine if Android app is being used for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636141/determine-if-android-app-is-being-used-for-the-first-time)

Comment: By using a boolean flag (e.g. `isFirstTime`) and `SharedPreference`s.

Comment: Use sharedPref to store a boolean value and check that value whenever your app is run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are looking at storing large or complicated data you can save it with room database. if you need to store simple data you can use shared preferences.

you can save a variable in shared preferences such as isFirstTimeUser=true or false then you can check this variable when the app starts. If it is the users first time to use the app present them with ui to create the fields you require. If not then proceed to fetch the details