# Will WorkManager's queue be cleared in case of an app update?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

At every app start I enqueue periodic work using ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, so that no additional work is queued if there is already a schedule.

Let's assume that in a future app update, I change the constraints or periodicity of the work, but keep the original `uniqueName`.
will this change be ignored because the `PeriodicWorkRequest` uses the same `uniqueWorkName`?

Or will this not be a problem because all work for an app is cancelled when the app is updated?

What's the best approach here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you update your app the scheduled work is maintained.

If you want to modify the `workRequest` the only option is to cancel the previous request and register a new one.

I don't see this as a WorkManager specific problem as a new application version may require to do some action just once (onboarding a new feature, migrating some preferences, modifying some WorkManager work, etc). There are some useful answers  using SharedPreferences in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636141/determine-if-android-app-is-being-used-for-the-first-time).

I would add this WorkRequest change in the section of your application that handles upgrades.

Answer (score 5):

As [WorkManager | Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager) stated, You can set specific `Tag` to `WorkRequest` in addition to `uniqueWorkName`. Indeed, you can preserve `uniqueWorkName` without worrying about it.

When you need to change constraints of the `WorkRequest` you need to first, Eliminate the old-fashioned `WorkRequest` from the queue then add a new-fashioned one to the queue.

Here is some piece of code

```
PeriodicWorkRequest request = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(FooWorker.class)
    .addTag("m_TAG_Version_1")
    .build();
workManager
    .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("uniqueWorkName", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, request);
```

Then in future

```
if(isWorkUpdated)
{
    workManager.cancelAllWorkByTag("m_TAG_Version_1");
    PeriodicWorkRequest request = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(FooWorker.class)
        .addTag("m_TAG_Version_2")
        .build();
    workManager
        .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("uniqueWorkName", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, request);
}
```